# Can't able to start MySQL server

Tags: mysql

I got following error when I try to start or check the status of MySQL server.

[image]

Then I try to get mysql log from /var/log/mysql/error.log and I got this message.

```
2022-11-14T01:37:18.685414Z 731 [Warning] [MY-010057] [Server] IP address '130.211.54.158' has been resolved to the host name '158.54.211.130.bc.googleusercontent.com', which resembles IPv4-address itself.
2022-11-14T01:37:19.353214Z 732 [Warning] [MY-010057] [Server] IP address '34.140.248.32' has been resolved to the host name '32.248.140.34.bc.googleusercontent.com', which resembles IPv4-address itself.
2022-11-14T02:48:31.794184Z 734 [Warning] [MY-010058] [Server] Hostname 'security.criminalip.com' does not resolve to '94.102.61.23'.
2022-11-14T06:43:32.440236Z 0 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user <via user signal>. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.31-0ubuntu0.20.04.1).
2022-11-14T06:43:33.329334Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.31-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
```

Another log for command:  `systemctl status mysql.service`

[image]

Comment: What happens if you run /usr/sbin/mysqld-debug?

Comment: Can't able to solve and later reset Ubuntu. Thank you for your reply.